# Attempting to count cells in Excel using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As the title states, I am trying to count across cell ranges on a separate sheet but cant seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
=COUNTIFS(MONTH(original!A2:A58),"1",original!D2:D58,"=East")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the [MONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Month-Function-78182042-7BF0-46E9-829E-C7012F773FC5) as a form of sub-function in a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). You need to add an extra level of calculation with something like a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff).

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(original!A2:A58)=1)*(original!D2:D58="East"))
```

That should count the instances where the month of the date in the Original worksheet's column A is January and the corresponding row's column D is East.

If you prefer to stay with a COUNTIFS and can keep the dates to a single year, you can provide a start date and end date which will bracket the month of January for a particular year.

```
=COUNTIFS(Original!A2:A58,">="&DATE(2015,1,1),Original!A2:A58,"<"&DATE(2015,2,1),Original!D2:D58,"East")
```

The default comparison operator for COUNTIFS is *equals*. There is no need to type it in.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `Month()` part in your formula. I understand your logic, but you'll have to probably add a new column on the Original sheet that has the month formula conversion there, then update the countif to reference it.

```
COUNTIFS(Original!monthcol, "1", Original!col, "East")
```

Again, in summary the Month formula can't do the conversion for an entire range of cells in the CountIf. The only other way would require an array formula. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh no worries! Glad you got it figured out!